# Not able to open terminal

Tags: python, gnome-terminal

I am using ubuntu 16.04.
The shortcut keys for gnome-terminal is not working.
 So when I try to run gnome-terminal from XTerm error it gives the following error -

```
bash: /usr/bin/gnome-terminal: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The command used that was used was ctrl+alt+t.
It seems that I have deleted the python 3.5 executable from `/usr/bin` directory.

Comment: What is the _shortcut key_, how are you running it from the _Xterm_ ? Please be a bit more explicit.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, gnome-terminal (like many other things) depends on python3. Did you change anything in your python setup?

Comment: It seems that i deleted the python executable from  /usr/bin

Comment: On 16.04, ` /usr/bin/python3` is (should be) a link to `/usr/bin/python3.5`.  What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python3.5` (run from `XTerm` :) )

Comment: It displays the following error -
ls : cannot access '/usr/bin/python3.5': No such file or directory

Comment: Did you ever deliberately change anything in your python setup? Removed python3? Many things should be broken if python3 is gone.

Comment: Are you sure you're on Ubuntu 16.04? What's the output of `lsb_release -a`, `apt-cache policy python3 python3.5-minimal`, and `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster yiu might have a point, the tag mentions 14.04. Which is it?

Comment: Yea.The software centre is also not working . I changed by default python version to 3.5 from  2.7 and then I wanted to change it to 2.7 in that process I deleted the python3.5 executable

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Output of apt-cache policy python3 python3.5-minimal is the following -
http://pastebin.com/A4RaHvEb

Output of ls -l /usr/bin/python* is the following - 
http://pastebin.com/BNqWs0WB
"/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5" is displayed in red